# What does the symbol "~" mean in VCL?

Tags: varnish

I am seeing that this is used in **varnish vcl** if statements **"~"**

```
if (req.url ~ "phpMyAdmin") {
    return (pass);
}
```

I understand that it works like **`==`** some time like **`in_array()`**

```
if ( req.http.User-Agent ~ "(Android|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|SAMSUNG)") 
   return(pass);
}
```

Can someone please explain what does it actually mean.
Is it also a default php operator? and what's the difference between it and using **`==`**

Comment: This symbol is called "tilde"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/users-guide/vcl-syntax.html#operators), `~` is the **match operator**.

`==` compares two values, returns true if they are equal

`~` checks the value against the regular expression, returns true if the value is a match

> **~** **Match**. Can either be used with regular expressions or ACLs.

```
# match an IP address against an ACL
if (client.ip ~ local) {
  return (pipe);
}
```

> Varnish uses Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE). To send flags to the PCRE engine, such as to do case insensitive matching, add the flag within parens following a question mark, like this:

```
# If host is NOT example dot com..
if (req.http.host !~ "(?i)example\.com$") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is correct. The most common use is "Is this substring anywhere in this variable?". This is not a php operator, php has nothing to do with Varnish.

Answer (score -3):

I think there is no any symbol like "~" in php.

Already checked with php documentation.

[image]

Comment: Bitwise Operators in PHP has similar symbol, now I understand better that varnish is not related with PHP.